# Radio button switch statements

Tags: forms, if-statement, switch-statement

```
    <input type="radio" name="deckung" id="Basis-Deckung" value="737.80" onClick="DisplayPrice()">
    <input name="deckungname" type="hidden" id="StartUp-Deckung" value="StartUp-Deckung">
    <input name="selbstb" type="hidden" id="selbst_startUp" value="500,- EUR">


    <input type="radio" name="deckung" id="Standard-Deckung" value="1368.50" onClick="DisplayPrice()">
    <input name="deckungname" type="hidden" id="Standard-Deckung" value="Standard-Deckung">  
    <input name="selbstb" type="hidden" id="selbst_standard" value="1.500,- EUR">       



    <input type="radio" name="deckung" id="Premium-Deckung" value="1785.00" onClick="DisplayPrice()">
    <input name="deckungname" type="hidden" id="Premium-Deckung" value="Premium-Deckung">
    <input name="selbstb" type="hidden" id="selbst_premium" value="2.000,- EUR">
```

Hello Guys,

i have a big problem, i want to transfer the values of the two hidden fields under the deckung field.

```
    if 
    {
    $deckung == '737.48';
        echo 'deckungsname=StartUp-Deckung;  selbstb='500,-';
    }
    elseif $deckung == '1368.50';
    { 
            echo 'deckungsname=Standard-Deckung;  selbstb='1.500,- EUR';
    }
    elseif $deckung == '1785.00';
    { 
            echo 'deckungsname=Premium-Deckung;  selbstb='2.000,- EUR';
    }
```

Hope i could explain what i want to to do!

Can see the Form here: [Formular](http://cominaction.de/step1.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$deckung = $_POST['deckung'];
if($deckung == '737.48') {
        echo "deckungsname=StartUp-Deckung;  selbstb=500,-'";
    }
    elseif ($deckung == '1368.50')
    { 
            echo "deckungsname=Standard-Deckung;  selbstb=1.500,- EUR";
    }
    elseif ($deckung == '1785.00')
    { 
            echo "deckungsname=Premium-Deckung;  selbstb=2.000,- EUR";
    }
```